# Docker desktop is giving docker daemon error

Tags: windows, docker, docker-desktop

I have installed `docker desktop`.

When I am doing docker version, it is throwing an error:
[image]

I have tried:

1. In services, I have checked the docker service is running or not.
2. Updated the WSL package from: https://wslstorestorage.blob.core.windows.net/wslblob/wsl_update_x64.msi

Still it is giving the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error should be a matter of wrong privileges. So, try to run Docker Desktop with admin privilege.

If the error persist, you should:

- open Docker Desktop
- open a terminal (cmd or powershell) as administrator and type the command `"C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\DockerCli.exe" -SwitchDaemon`